# Jersey 2.x add multiple headers to ClientConfig

Tags: java, http-headers, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I've looked at different answers on here and they're all about adding header(s) during a request call. I would like to add headers in the client config then register it with the client itself.

I've looked around and found that I can create a custom **ClientRequestFilter**, but looking at the `add()` method signatures, I don't see any in which I can add multiple headers - they all take like a string as the first argument, then like a list.

For example, I would like to add these headers:

```
Accept: 'something'
Client-ID: 'another something'
Authorization: 'OAuth more something'
```

I came up with the code below, but it seems only the first `register()` method call is actually used. I checked the debugger and all I see is the first **Accept** header and the User-Agent header added by Jersey.

```
public OAuth2Authenticator(String header, String value) {
    this.header = header;
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    requestContext.getHeaders().add(header, value);
}


...

client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig());
client.register(new OAuth2Authenticator(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, API_VERSION))
      .register(new OAuth2Authenticator("Client-ID", clientId))
      .register(new OAuth2Authenticator(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "OAuth " + accessToken));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by assigning to a MultivalueMap first, then calling `add()`.

```
MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "something");
headers.add("Client-ID", another something);
headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "OAuth more something");

...

client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig());
client.register(new OAuth2Authenticator( API_VERSION, clientId, accessToken));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do :

```
client.target("")
             .request()
             .header("Accept","something")
             .header("Client-ID", "another something");
```

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, I know you can add headers like that. But I need to make different calls that uses different `path("asdf")`, and from what I can tell, once you set the headers, you cannot change the path - without calling `target()` again first. Which means I'd have to repeatedly call `header()` and `path()` in some way...